# How can I get all coordinates inside the ROI region (created by imfreehand)?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

Sorry if my question is elementary.
I want to calculate CT values for certain region of DICOM pictures. I used imfreehand to draw the ROI, but the coordinates I got (via getposition function) are only about the boundary. 
How can I get the coordinates inside the region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `createMask()` method of the `imfreehand` object to create a binary mask, and then `find` to get xy coordinates:

```
% your original image
imshow(zeros(100));
% imfreehand
h = imfreehand;
% create a mask and get coordinates
mask = h.createMask();
[y,x] = find(mask);
```